# Folder being created in C:\ProgramData called GufeSoman. Keeps coming back?

Tags: windows, virus

It has been brought to my attention by my antivirus that a certain file is a dangerous trojan. I removed it. However, the folder (GufeSoman) keeps recreating itself whenever I delete it. I have found no unusual processes running (unsure about services) so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Simple approach to start would be to run a full antivirus scan. There is a deamon or something running that is recreating that folder. Also try doing the scan and removal in safe mode. Not a guarentee but it might be easier. Any other odd behavior

Comment: What the name of the file, the name of the folder isn't english, so can you translate it for us?

Comment: Run ProcMon with a filter to this folder and look which process creates it again: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-4-Process-Monitor

Comment: Matt My antivirus found it when I ran a full scan. Ramhound I cant remeber the name of the file but it ended with .lep, it's the folder that is being recreated, but not the file... magicandre1981 I'm going to try that now, I'll let you know what comes up.

Comment: @magicandre1981 According to ProcMon, explorer.exe and ekm.exe are creating the folder. Weird. ekm.exe is part of my antivirus by the way.

Comment: Turns out my antivirus was immediately quarantining the offending file. It is called TekxOvbu.lep

Comment: I can't find anything in a search engine. Look like malware. So delete the guarantee and scan your PC with other tools like Malwarebytes to make sure the PC is no clean.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Before I looked at your comment I had asked a few friends and they recommended MalwareBytes. Turns out it was a fake explorer.exe and MB found a few other threats. I've done 3 scans and I'm clean. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: nice to hear this. Enjoy your PC now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Task Manager, go to Details then find any duplicate instances of a process such as explorer.exe. Use Malwarebytes to scan and remove any malware.

Comment: Nice find. For future readers: it's not uncommon to see duplicates of the very same process, but in this specific case, one `explorer.exe` was apparently different from the other(s).